# Common fix for Gnome title bar resize doesn't work universally

Tags: css, window, gnome

Gnome scaling does not work automatically on window bars, so a common question is how to resize them, and the common answer is to add a file called `gtk.css` to `~.config/gtk-3.0/` which works for most windows. Some windows however, like the extension window, keep their tall bar. My only guess was to copy the `gtk.css` file to each numbered version of gtk in `~.config,` which did not work.

My file structure and the contents of `gtk.css` are:

```
~ $ tree .config/gtk-*

.config/gtk-2.0
├── gtk.css
└── gtkfilechooser.ini
.config/gtk-3.0
├── bookmarks
├── gtk.css
└── settings.ini
.config/gtk-4.0
├── gtk.css
└── settings.ini


~ $ cat .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css 

.titlebar, headerbar {
    min-height: 0px;
    max-height: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    min-height: 0px;
    max-height: 4px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

I included an image of a title bar that works as expected, and one that does not.[image: comparison of reduced and non reduced title bars]

Answer (score 2):

Some applications have a taller header bar because they are leaving room for a subtitle. Since the default is to leave room for a subtitle, and the developer has to explicitly turn that off, many applications will have extra-tall header bars even though they never use subtitles.

The [GtkHeaderBar docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html) say,

> The height of the titlebar will be set to provide sufficient space for
> the subtitle, even if none is currently set. If a subtitle is not needed,
> the space reservation can be turned off with
> `gtk_header_bar_set_has_subtitle().`

If you follow the [GtkInspector instructions](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GTK/Inspector)

> The debugger is disabled by default. To enable it, make sure you have the
> `libgtk-3-dev`(debian-naming) or `gtk3-devel`(fedora-naming) package
> installed and run in a terminal:
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
> ```
>
> [… some stuff about flatpak …]
>
> To launch the GTK Inspector, focus your GTK application and press
> `Control-Shift-D`. Alternatively, move your mouse cursor to your desired
> widget and press `Control-Shift-I` to specifically inspect the widget under
> the mouse cursor.

then you can toggle the has-subtitle property on and off to see the difference:

[image: thick header bar when has-subtitle=true]

[image: thin header bar when has-subtitle=false]

Unfortunately I’m not aware of a way to override this property for an application using CSS or a config file; it may need a code change to GTK or the application itself.

<sup><sub>That said, since GTKInspector can toggle this property, there’s probably some API/protocol you can use to emulate whatever it’s doing.</sub></sup>